# No Group Memberships option in the Azure AD Group blade

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a security group called SecurityGroupParent and another security group called SecurityGroupChild. I want to add SecurityGroupChild as a member to SecurityGroupParent. But I cannot see the option Group Memberships as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/how-to-manage-groups#add-or-remove-a-group-from-another-group) although I have the right role.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- You'll need the ***`Groups Administrator`*** or ***`User Administrator`*** role to
  edit group membership.
- Also please check if you have logged into correct tenant or account in
  which you have above roles before adding membership.

[image]

Also please note that there are some limits while using nesting of groups.
*For example*: ***We cannot add group which is synced with on-premises Active Directory.***
See [***Limitations - groups - Azure Active Directory - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs***](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/how-to-manage-groups#add-or-remove-a-group-from-another-group)

[image]

You can also try to add child security group as a member to the parent security group from members blade:

[image]

1. ***If the groups are set to role assignable or IsAssignableToRole is
   set to $True, then the groups are `private` and only members can view
   the content of the group.***
2. Also check , if ***`HiddenMembership`*** is enabled. reference: [visibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsgroup?view=azureadps-2.0#:%7E:text=False-,%2DVisibility,-Specifies%20the%20visibility)

Comment: Thanks for you response Kavya!
- I have all these three roles (Global administrator, Groups administrator, User administrator) assigned to my account that I'm signed in with.
- I'm signed in in the correct tenant and with the correct account.
- These groups doesn't fall under the limitations.
- I cannot find groups when searching in the Members blade

Comment: Can you please try adding the membership using the powershell using objectId of the groups.See [commandlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-settings-v2-cmdlets) and see if it works or gives any error

Comment: So I ran this command Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId 123456 -RefObjectId 789123 and got Add-AzureADGroupMember: Error occurred while executing AddGroupMember 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: An invalid operation was included in the following modified references: 'members'.